# Ajuste de tabla con la etiqueta nav

Tags: css, html-tabla

Tengo unas dudas respecto a HTML y CSS. 
¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ponga a un lado la tabla del menú que tengo a la izquierda?

Este es el código:

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: justify;
}
.container{
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 120%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}
header{
 background-color: orange;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 1em; 
align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
#nav {
   width: 11em;
   padding: 0 0.5em;
   background-color: #ddd;
}

#nav {
   float: left;
   width: 11em;
   padding: 0 0.5em;
   background-color: #ddd;
}
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 14em 0 12em;
   padding: 0 1em;
}
#main {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: ;
}
#nav {
   float: left;
   width: 11em;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #ddd;
   margin-left: -100%;

}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 176px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3393FF;
  color: white;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width-device,initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="ie-edge">
 <title>Módulo de Atención Eléctronica</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
  <header>
 <h2>MAE</h2>
<div class="inline divTitle"> Módulo de Atención Eléctronica</div>   
  </header>
     <container>
       <div id="main">Tabla</div>
       <div id="nav" style="color:orange">Menú</div>
       <br>
   <ul>
  <li><a href="#solicitudes">Solicitudes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Notificaciones">Notificaciones</a></li>
  <li><a href="#SolicitudNueva">Nueva Solicitud</a></li>
  <li style="color:orange">Herramientas</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.anterior.banxico.org.mx/"class="menu-link">Portal Banxico</a></li>
</ul>
  <table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Folio</th>
    <th>No.Oficio</th>
    <th>Solicitante</th>
    <th>Fecha de Recibido</th>
    <th>Servicio</th>
    <th>Días Otorgadas</th>
    <th>Fecha de Alta</th>
    <th>Última persona que actualizó</th>
    <th>Observaciones</th>
  </tr>
  
</table>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola David, qué quieres decir con poner a un lado? A qué lado?

Comment: Hola cristina, seria del lado derecho a lado del menú

Answer (score 0):

Agregando un display:block al siguiente selector

```
#customers th {
  display:block;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #3393FF;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: hola Leandro gracias por la respuesta pero se me acomoda debajo del menú que ya tengo, lo que necesitaba hacer es ponerlo al lado derecho podrías orientarme?

Comment: Ok, entonces hacè esto, encerrá entre Divs la tabla. hace otro div que va desde el div 'main' incluyendo el ul. Luego colocà un div que englobe a estos ùltimos dos y colocale una propiedad CSS display:inline-flex. https://jsfiddle.net/leandrolisa64/2o6hdubt/

Comment: Listo muchas gracias leandro